# XML Element Name

Tags: xml, asp-classic, selectnodes

I am hoping there is a simple answer that I am over looking, but I've searched for a couple of hours and can't seem to find the answer. Also, I'm stuck using classic asp. 
I just need to get the text for the first element of this XML structure.

```
 <section href="multifamily">For Multifamily 
   <item href="resources.htm">Resources</item> 
   <item href="vacancy-rates">Rental Vacancy Rates</item> 
   <item href="multiFamily-update">Multifamily Update Newsletter</item> 
 </section>
```

I am for some reason unable to get the text, "Multifamily", while looping through the entire XML file.

Here is some of the code I have so far:

```
Sub findName(xmlObject)

Set sections = objXMLDoc.SelectNodes(XMLObject.ObjType)
countSections(sections)

End Sub

Sub countSections(sections)

Response.write(sections.length)
If sections.length > 1 Then
    putInArray(sections)
End IF
End Sub

Sub putInArray(sections)
Dim section

''For Each section In sections
''  Response.write(section.innerText)
''Next
For i = 0 To sections.length -1
    Response.write(sections.item(0).text)
Next

End Sub
```

I really appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the XML is invalid. You can either have nodes within a node or text...not both. You'll need to put "For Multifamily" within a node or use it as an attribute. e.g.

```
<section href="multifamily">
  <newnode>For Multifamily </newnode>
  <item href="resources.htm">Resources</item> 
  <item href="vacancy-rates">Rental Vacancy Rates</item> 
  <item href="multiFamily-update">Multifamily Update Newsletter</item> 
</section>
```

or

```
<section href="multifamily" newattribute="For Multifamily">
  <item href="resources.htm">Resources</item> 
  <item href="vacancy-rates">Rental Vacancy Rates</item> 
  <item href="multiFamily-update">Multifamily Update Newsletter</item> 
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I have figured out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, which as I suppected was something I was overlooking. Here is the answer in case someone else has the same question:

```
For i=0 To ObjNodes.length -1
    Response.write(ObjNodes(i).firstChild.text &"<br />")

Next
```

I just needed to grab the first child instead of all the children. I hope this helps someone else in the future.